# beamer: uncover table by row when number of cells is not constant

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, border, cell

The first row of the table has one cell, but the second row has 2.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\RequirePackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\cline{1-1}%
a  \\ \cline{1-2}%
\noalign{\pause}%
b & c
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The 2 slides look like
[image]
and
[image]

How to make the top border of the cell c only appear on the second slide ?
Playing with `\cline` argument gives an error, combining with `\alt` gives an error as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

[image: a]

To add the top line for the right cell in the second slide --with a `\cline{2-2}`-- you need a `\\` and then subtract the baseline skip using `\\[<length>]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\RequirePackage{array}

\newlength{\vshift}
\setlength{\vshift}{-\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \cline{1-1}%
            a  \\ \cline{1-1}% this finish the "a" cell
            \noalign{\pause}%
            \\[\the\vshift]\cline{2-2}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
            b & c
            \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Alternative** using `tikz`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}    

\tikzset{
    boxed/.style={draw,%
        line width=0.25pt,
        inner sep=1.0mm,% %expand the square
        outer sep=0,%
        minimum width=height("b")+2*1.0mm,% twice the inner separation
        minimum height=height("b")+2*1.0mm,% equal to width
        align=center}
}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style= boxed]
        \node (a) {a}; 
        \pause
        \node [below = 0mm of a.south] (b) {b}; 
        \node [right =  0mm of b.east] (c) {c}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain in more details why a new length is needed in that situation?

Comment: @Jérôme LAURENS The  \\ inside a tabular is implemented by `\@tabularcr` of the LaTeX kernel. If there is an optional argument with a (positive  or negative) length, the macro  adds that  length to the default depth of the line and puts an invisible rule with the new depth. By the way it is defined expects a proper dimension like `20pt` or `-2ex`. Commands like `\bigskip` or  `-\baselineskip` that need to be expanded do not work (Try yourself!). In this case `[\the\vshift]` is equivalent to `[-13.6pt]` so it works fine.

Comment: The `\vshift` must be adjusted if the row height is not standard: for example when `\arraystretch` is not 1 or a `>{\vphantom{...}}` trick is used .

Comment: @Jérôme LAURENS  It is true, Perhaps a tikz solution best suits your requirements. See the added alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a dirty-messy way of doing it, but you could simply use one tabular after another.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\RequirePackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{|m{0.01\textwidth}|}
\hline
a \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\pause
\\[-0.25ex]
\begin{tabular}{|m{0.01\textwidth}|m{0.01\textwidth}|}
\hline
b & c
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Notice the use of constant width columns because otherwise the 'a' and the 'b' column would be of different width